# Finding a refinement upper bounds for summation 1 to n with a fixed natural power

Tags: calculus, number-theory, summation

Consider $p$ be a fixed positive integer and we know this trivial inequality is hold.$$1^p+2^p+ \cdots +n^p \leq n^{p+1}.$$
But we would search for a refinement upper bounds for $1^p+2^p+ \cdots +n^p $,such that state according to well-defined functions.
Any help for this will be appreciated.

Comment: Do you mean that the refined upper bound should be stated in terms of elementary functions? what do you mean by "well-defined" functions?

Comment: Yes, I mean the refined upper bound should be stated in terms of elementary functions.

Comment: What about the application of the Faulhaber-formula?

Answer (score 3):

Since $x^p$ is convex, $k^p\le \int_{k-1/2}^{k+1/2}x^p dx$, so
$$
\sum_{k=1}^n k^p \le \int_{1/2}^{n+1/2} x^p dx = \frac{(2n+1)^{p+1}-1}{2^{p+1} (p+1)}.
$$

Answer (score 2):

The Faulhaber-formulae give the exact expression:
$$\small \begin{array} {r|llll}
 p & f_p(n) \\ \hline
 0 & n \\ 
 1 & 1/2 n^{p+1}&+ 1/2 n \\ 
 2 & 1/3 n^{p+1}&+ 1/2 n^p&+1/6 n^ {p-1}& \\ 
 3 & 1/4 n^{p+1}&+ 1/2 n^p&+1/4 n^ {p-1}&0 \\ 
 4 & 1/5 n^{p+1}&+1/2 n^p&+1/3 n^ {p-1}&0&-1/30 n^ {p-3}
 \end{array}
$$
From this an inequality in your style can be derived by simply ignoring trailing coefficients of less power.